# How to create a circle with specific radius?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conflicting measurement units with buffer ftools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16513/conflicting-measurement-units-with-buffer-ftools)

I have a shapefile as input. How could I create a circle with a radius of exactly 500 meters, using QGIS?

Comment: Circles don't have 'lengths'.

Comment: Do you mean a [radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius), [diameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter), or [circumference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference) of 500m?

Comment: yes the radius is 500 meters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a polygon that is like a circle, you can select a point, then use Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Buffer(s). Set the buffer distance to the desired radius.

Note that it will be a polygon when you save it to a shapefile. It'll look round at some scales though :-)