# Does QGIS support true circular curves?

Tags: qgis, true-curves

As a land surveyor, I often bring cad data into a GIS and create polygon representing parcels.  Traditional tools I have for cleaning topology are inappropriate so I am looking for something different - even if it means teaming up with someone to build additional extensions.  (I scanned the list of existing extensions and some pieces are already there).  My idea is to fix minor topology errors by constraining key geometric elements. That is, straight polylines and circular arcs which share a common centre point.  A key requirement is support for true circular curves.  I could keep the data in SQL Server but prefer a GUI for a better user experience.  As I am not familiar with QGIS, I am looking for some indication if the data structure used by QGIS can support this.

Comment: See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155383/115

Comment: Those answers are good *but* some geometry storage types don't support curves, shapefiles for example do not, if you digitize a curve into one of these features it will be *stroked* either immediately or on saving edits.. this would still look alright for mapping purposes but the real drama begins when you try to edit the curve, it's no longer two points with a centroid and radius but multiple (possibly hundreds) short segments approximating a curve. You need to choose a storage type that supports curves: both file and personal geodatabase support true curves and so does PostGIS.

Comment: You should always choose geopackage over geodatabases if you need to step outside the esri ecosystem