# Drawing Circles with set radius using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, circle

I have a site and want to draw an indicative line in a 5km buffer around the centre of the site. So I want to draw a circle with a radius of 5km. I have a tool for drawing circles and ellipses and rectangles squares and spirals.

None of these let me state the centre point and the radius.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conflicting measurement units with buffer ftools](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16513/conflicting-measurement-units-with-buffer-ftools)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As [commented by @Roy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29509/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-a-set-radius#comment39562_29509):

> Drop a point (x,y), buffer the point 5km.

i.e. you could make a point in layer and then buffer it into a new layer.

---

The workflow I have recently been using is to create the point in a Memory Layer, create the buffer into a shapefile saved in a temporary location, then copy and paste the polygon into the final layer. A bit long but works OK.

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar - need to draw 5km circles around a set of points meeting some criteria. I solved the problem using styles:

1. Create a Symbology rule for the layer (in my case ": "field" is not null
2. For the symbol, define a 'Simple Marker"

   - Size 10000.0 (the size is diameter, not radius
   - Units, select "Meters at Scale"
   - Fill color: Transparent

Voila! A range ring at true map scale.

I'm using QGis 3.10, which is much newer than when this question was originally asked.

Comment: Great method if your purpose is visualisation rather than further processing!

Answer (score 3):

With mmqgis plugin you can convert your geometry type to centroids :

*Plugins > mmqgis > modify > convert geometry type*

And then just create buffers on shapes (*through Vector > Geoprocessing tools*) and precise the desired radius.

You got it

Answer (score 3):

Possible by means of the `"Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds"` geoalgorithm from the QGIS's Toolbox, using *'Ovals'*, either *fixed* or *variable*.

[image: example]

*Note:* That both 'Width' and 'Height' parameters have to be equal.

---

**References:**

- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 23.1.15.56. Rectangles, ovals, diamonds (fixed)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds-fixed)
- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 23.1.15.57. Rectangles, ovals, diamonds (variable)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds-variable)

Answer (score 3):

In QGis 3.16 I discovered the'Geometry Shapes' plug-in.
The symbol/tool shows up in the digitize toolbar. A very handy plug-in!

[image: Geometry shapes plug-in]

Comment: 'Geometry Shapes' plug-in Worked as suggested. You can use it to draw circle or ellipse

Comment: The "Draw rectangle geometry" and Draw oval geometry" options are disabled for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Consider also using "Geometry Generator" which contains a function `make_circle($geometry, 100)`, see image below.

[image: example]

> **function make_circle**
> Creates a circular polygon.
>
> **Syntax**
> make_circle(center,radius[,segment=36]…)
> [ ] marks optional components
>
> **Arguments**
> *center* center point of the circle
> *radius* radius of the circle
> *segment* optional argument for polygon segmentation. By default, this value is
> 36
>
> **Examples**
> `geom_to_wkt(make_circle(make_point(10,10), 5, 4))` → `'Polygon ((10 15, 15 10, 10 5, 5 10, 10 15))'`
> `geom_to_wkt(make_circle(make_point(10,10,5), 5, 4))` → `'PolygonZ ((10 15 5, 15 10 5, 10 5 5, 5 10 5, 10 15 5))'`
> `geom_to_wkt(make_circle(make_point(10,10,5,30), 5, 4))` → `'PolygonZM ((10 15 5 30, 15 10 5 30, 10 5 5 30, 5 10 5 30, 10 15 5 30))'`

Answer (score 0):

While developing a standalone qgis application, I shot help from [QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) many times and it is very helpful. For drawing different geometries like Rectangle, Circle, Oval and Ellipse etc. [this plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rectovalDigit/) is of great help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that plugin has a problem: THIS PLUGIN IS NO LONGER ACTIVELY MAINTAINED.
PLEASE UPDATE TO FIX A CRITICAL BUG THAT SLOWS DOWN QGIS AND CONSIDER TO DEINSTALL THE PLUGIN AND USE CADDIGITIZE INSTEAD