# Drawing perfect circle with set radius in meters on map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, circle

Following this istructions on [how to draw a circle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29509/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-a-set-radius) I can make buffer layer on each point I need.

I am not able to draw perfects circle because the buffer will be elliptic?

The CSR is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

And I am also not able to set unit misure in meters as I need (300 meters)

Where is my error? I use QGIS 1.8 on windowx 7

Comment: How large are your buffers? Maybe you run into distortion because of the projection you are using.

Comment: The set radius I need is 300 meters. The difference between tho axes is a lot (the ratio is 4:3)

Comment: Whats the projection/crs you use?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using QGis 2.4 on Windows and a UTM 32N projection (EPSG:4647).

Comment: The projection is WGS84 and the location I need to work is Italy

Comment: In WGS84 the east-west distances and south-north distances look the same only at the equator. The closer to the poles you are the more flattened the circle will look.

Comment: I use geoprocessing/buffer option to create the new layer. If I use measure option I find around 310 meters as orizontal lenght (latitude) and around 420 meters as vertical one (longitude)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a **projected** CRS like UTM (for your part of the world) to get real circles and meters as units.

Please do not use Google/Web Mercator, it does not use real meters as units (only at the equator).

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose a suitable UTM grid for your area (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM-Koordinatensystem#mediaviewer/File:LA2-Europe-UTM-zones.png ), probably 32 or 33 (north).
2. Save your layer in the chosen UTM coordinate system.
3. Use the buffer tool on the new UTM layer.